# How do I add logs to MongooseIM logs?

Tags: erlang, chat, message, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am trying to modify some APIs in MongooseIM and I want to see some logs. I tried adding lager-logging using MongooseIM, but the APIs stopped working after that.

Comment: I think it would help you get some answers if you were more specific about what you tried (code snippets?), what you're getting, and what you're expecting instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code, you can add debug statement into it and compile it to beam file then replace the old file. The debug statement is to write some log into log file. I have used this method solving the problem in rabbitmq before.